# Different models in R's plm function

Tags: r, regression, panel-data

I am having trouble understanding different model parameters used in R's plm function. Specifically, I have a data sets with 2 independent variables X and Y as well as a dummy variable Z. Can someone help me with the following two lines of codes and see if they are actually equivalent?

```
plm(Y~X, data, model='within')
```

vs

```
lm(Y~X+Z, data)
```

Comment: Y is dependent on X. A good way to check is to see if the model estimates give you similar results. A reproducible example is always helpful.

Comment: Would you please post the data, or a link to the data?

Comment: @MWaz if the regression is of the type "z = f(x, y)" then both x and y are independent.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Please look at the code. Y~X in the function call tells us that y is the dependent variable in this case so your example is irrelevant.

Comment: Why would these be equivalent? To my understanding, the `plm` function's `within` argument just estimates a fixed effects model, but regardless the `lm` function here doesn't include your dummy variable.